# remove index.php url rewriting .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'd written this code for `301 redirect`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

It is working well in case if I do visit my site as `http://mysite.com/index.php`, it redirects me to `http://mysite.com`

But on my `localhost` if I try to visit `index.php` as `localhost/mysite/index.php` it redirects me to `localhost`.

How could I solve this problem? Is the code written above is correct?

Comment: On your localhost, you need to add `RewriteBase /mysite/` above those lines since the site isn't at the root of server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have your htaccess file in your document root on your server, and in the `mysite` directory on localhost. Since the location of the htaccess file is pretty important on how it routes URIs, you need to make it indifferent to the location of the file. You can do this by extracting the path info from your condition instead of the URI that's passed into the rule to match against:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

---

The `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable is the first line of the actual HTTP request, which looks something like:

```
GET /path/index.php HTTP/1.1
```

The pattern first matches any number of possible *METHODS* (GET, POST, HEAD, etc), then it creates a grouping of the URI path that's *before* the `index.php`, then ends the matching, since we don't really care what's after the `index.php`.

Comment: how do this code works `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ )`? a little explanation on elements

Comment: still not working on `localhost`. I'd been redirected to `localhost` instead of `localhost/mysite`

Comment: Does it capture the URL parameters?

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: [r=301,nc] The [nc] specifies that the http host is case insensitive.

Comment: and what does `L` specifies?

Comment: OPs issue is not with uppercase/lowercase, it is with the site base.

Comment: @dleiftah: what should I do in this case?

Comment: L=Last ... no more rewrites will be processed after that one. I put a comment on the question about adding the `RewriteBase` directive

Comment: @dleiftah some times its create problem thats why case is required ohterwise code seems perfect for both.

Comment: @dleiftah: post it in answer. If it worked for me, you will get answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

If your site is not at the root of the server (which it's not on your localhost), you will need to add a `RewriteBase` directive: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

You need to add the line:

```
RewriteBase /mysite/
```

above the current lines in the htaccess on your localhost

Comment: is there could be any solution that will work on both side (i.e., `localhost` and `server`)

Answer (score 0):

While `RewriteBase` directive stands for this usage, you may want to test for localhost and rewrite root to your subdirectory only if test == true. eg:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
RewriteRule (.*) /subdirectory/$1 [L]
```

Note I have not used this for some time and cannot guarantee you it'll work out of the box; might need some edit.