# How can I rewrite URL using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have already searched a lot, found a lot of articles, but nothing works.
I have create a test website and a test directory in it.

http://myexp.net63.net/apartment/index.php?id=999

I want this URL to shorten like the below.

http://myexp.net63.net/apartment/999

How can I do this using htaccess or any other way?

Comment: Please showcase some of the research and prior attempts.

Comment: I already did it, but no success, that why, I came here to post the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please show any effort in researching . This POST has been question and is duplicated several times here

SIMILAR POSTS

[Remove index.php From URL - Codeigniter 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2)

[Remove index.php from url by htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673235/remove-index-php-from-url-by-htaccess)

[CodeIgniter | .htaccess removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350137/codeigniter-htaccess-removing-index-php-from-url)

[htaccess remove index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url)

[remove index.php url rewriting .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742446/remove-index-php-url-rewriting-htaccess)

Comment: these links were helpful and helped me to get the work done. But not I want to reduce my URL further. I have shorten http://myexp.net63.net/page.php?id=6 to http://myexp.net63.net/page/6 but now I want to reduce http://myexp.net63.net/page/6 to http://myexp.net63.net/6 How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^apartment/([^/]*)$ /apartment/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Use this code in your .htaccess file

Comment: it didn't work. After adding these lines, when I visit the URL http://myexp.net63.net/apartment/999 it redirects me to the hosting server website.